# Jsp - Assigning java variable with html input type text in same jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to access one  tag in index.jsp page to fetch it's value and access the input tag html value to one java variable value in the same jsp page (index.jsp)

I am trying to use the variable to connect to database and fetch other details in the same jsp page but that html input tag value is not assigned to java variable using request object and tried in many ways but was unable to assign the value...

is there any method/idea to assign the html input tag=text value to java variable in same jsp page without using JSLT?

Appreciate your response

Comment: add jsps in your question and highlight what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to answer this because I've seen many green programmers get confused about this same exact subject for many HTML preprocessing languages (JSP in this case).  I'm going to start off right away saying this is an XY problem, please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

After reading about what an XY problem is, the actual problem here ("X"), is that you can't access HTML elements at time of user interaction with JSP.  JSP generates the HTML on the server.  The HTML is then sent to the Client, the JSP code is done, and no longer able to do anything with the page because it isn't on the server.  Now the HTML is on the client side and a user would enter the value you want.  The server really has no access to the page anymore and it is impossible for the JSP code that generated the page to access the value.

Essentially, it is not possible to access an HTML element with JSP without doing this another very different way (sending value by ajax or something).